# Setting up Spring Boot OAuth 2 Multi Authorization correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

- Spring Boot Version - 3.2 RC2 (same behavior with RC1)
- Keycloak as OpenID Connect server
- GitLab as OAuth 2 Auth server

I have a Spring Boot App (Client) which integrates with Keycloak for OpenID Connect. But I am also using GitLab as OAuth 2 to pull in all my GitLab projects. So, in my application.properties I have setup for both Keycloak and GitLab. The GitLab setup is NOT with openid scope because it's not intended for log in. This usecase works fine - I am able to login using keycloak and call the gitlab api by authorizing with Gitlab. SpringBoot stores both access tokens and I am able to access them.

However, when i try to log in to my app - Spring boot shows a login page with 2 links - one for Keycloak and another for GitLab. Is there any way to NOT show the gitlab link (because i don't want to log in with this) ?

In order to change login page,  I tried setting the login page as follows

```
oauth2Login.loginPage("{keycloak login url directly}")
```

Everything works with this - except I found out that the /logout was not working. When i looked at the console, I see that the DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter is missing from the list of filters. Not sure why. Why would DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter be missing if oauth2Login.loginPage() is used ?

Then I went and added this DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter back using HttpSecurity but when logging out, it gave me a 403 error. So, I am confused.

My original problem is that the "gitlab" link should not be shown in the login page.

Anyone has any ideas how to solve this ?

## My app.properties looks like this

```
# KeyCloak specific OAuth 2 related properties
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak-oidc.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak-oidc.client-name=Keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak-oidc.client-id=bugtracker
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak-oidc.client-secret=***********
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak-oidc.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak-oidc.scope=openid,profile,email

# provider url
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/realms/oauthcourse

# GitLab specific OAuth 2 related properties (GITLAB SHOWS UP IN LOGIN SCREEN)
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab-oidc.provider=gitlab
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab-oidc.client-name=GitLab
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab-oidc.client-id=11ea0ce2f44a0a81a6f0e5a5f622db814c56c8c565fe36a03ca9a0ea7da99821
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab-oidc.client-secret=******
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab-oidc.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.gitlab-oidc.scope=read_user,api,read_api

# provider url
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.gitlab.issuer-uri=https://gitlab.com
```

## security config

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
         authorize.requestMatchers("/bugtracker/ui").authenticated()
              .requestMatchers("/bugtracker/ui/admin/**").hasAnyRole("bugtracker.admin")
              .requestMatchers("/bugtracker/ui/**").hasAnyRole(<some list>)
              .anyRequest().authenticated())
    .oauth2Login(oauth2 ->
         oauth2.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-oidc") // <--- PROBLEM
               .userInfoEndpoint(epConfig -> epConfig.oidcUserService(...))
               .authorizationEndpoint(...))
    .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
    .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What defines that a client registration is used for login is the `authorization_code` flow (`authorization-grant-type`), not the scopes.

If you can declare a client with `client_credentials` on Github to make your Github API calls, then update your Spring conf. If not (if the request has to be done with an access token issued on behalf of a Github user with authorization-code flow), then you actually need to **login to both Keycloak and Github**. But you'll run into troubles because [Spring Security really isn't designed to hold multiple identities at a time](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12862). If that's the case, I suggest you add comment with your use case in the ticket...

Comment: OAuth [Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html#oauth2-client) doc does make a distinction between "login" versus "authorization" and that's what I am doing. The first (login) goes ahead and sets the Authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder. The second one (authorization) does not. I am using below code for authorization `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("gitlab-oidc") OAuth2AuthorizedClient client` Everything works fine except that the login page also shows gitlab. But I think there should be a way to mark a client as "not for log in"

Comment: An authorized client is a client with valid tokens, whatever the flow. Once **the user** logged in on authorization server using authorization_code, **the client** is authorized. The client can also run client_credentials by itself and get tokens from the authorization server without the help of a user. Just have a closer look at `AuthorizedClient` and flows definitions if you don't belive me.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I can't use client credentials here (it needs to be the logged in user). The point I am making is that there can be two `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` for auth flow for the same user and I can access the two tokens easily. I have it running currently. its just that the login page is not right. Not sure why you are saying its a problem. BTW - I am using latest Spring Boot 3.2

Comment: How is the Gitlab client authorized if it is configured with authorization_code and you don't login?

Comment: After logging in with Keycloak, there is a button in the application for getting GitLab Projects. That will initiate an an authorization code flow with gitlab. By using  `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("gitlab-oidc") OAuth2AuthorizedClient client` in my handling method, it handles the oauth flow automatically. This is how GitLab authorized client is set. The redirect endpoint is `/authorize/oauth2/code/gitlab-oidc` as opposed to `login/oauth2/code/gitlab-oidc`. That's what I mean by saying - login versus Authorization. This is as per doc link I added is prev comment.

Comment: Technically, a successful login leads to the creation of an authorized client, but I had missed this `/authorize/**` endpoints to add authorized client to the session of an already logged-in user and I now understand what you mean. My Bad. The default login page is generated by using all registrations with `authorization_code`. You could [override this default login page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-login-page), like you're trying to do, but mind the important note in the doc: **provide your own @Controller for it**

Comment: I have sample of such a [login @Controller here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/ui/LoginController.java). It goes with [this template](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui/src/main/resources/templates/login.html) (which is a copy of Spring's default one).

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. I created my own controller LoginController with /login. It works but there is still the problem of missing /logout. I think this is because - with new login Page change there is no DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter in the filter list. Not sure why. Is there anything specific to be done to get back the /logout ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. does your `oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()` return a `new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)`?

Comment: Yeah .. that's exactly what it does. But even after using `logout(Customizer.withDefaults())` - the /logout returns a 404

Comment: There must be something else in your conf that breaks logout, but without the full configuration and DEBUG logs, it's hard to tell (I don't know enough logout internal impl to make a guess).

Comment: I had to specifically set  `logout.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))` to get the /logout endpoint back. The only confusing part now is why spring boot does not ask for confirmation now. Thanks for the help !